# Submitting Dates between Date Range - mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert

In teaching myself php and mySQL a year or two ago, I created a movie database for the theater I work at, to help automate the more mundane web updates that need to be done weekly. So far this only pertains to film information (title, ratings, synopsis, start date) - but does not include showtimes, but lately I've thought it might be fun to see if it's possible to build on this aspect of the site.

My initial idea was to build a table that displayed showtimes via date groups (ie 5/15 - 5/20), but it was suggested that submitting times for individual days would probably be more useful from a user perspective (ie the showtimes for 5/15 are...), especially since there are occasionally changes and cancellations throughout the week due to special events.

Problem I'm having even starting this - is how to submit more than one date at once.  Would it be possible, in the form, to have a '**start date**' and '**end date**' and have the single form submit all the times input on those two dates and all the dates inbetween?

From a back-end perspective submitting the same 4 or 5 showtimes every day, 7 days a week for 10 to 14 films a week is more work for US than just putting the times in manually in dreamweaver - so I'm just trying to figure out how to make the process easier for us behind the scenes.  If we could batch insert a set of showtimes, then we could go back through and edit the individual days that have special/cancelled times (which would probably mean building in a 'draft, live, hidden' system - but I've got at least a basic knowledge of how to go about that.

I've got a very basic table set up for showtimes with (user end example of what I'm aiming for [here](http://codysilfies.com/p9test/display.php)):

- **MOVIE_ID**  (links with the movie info database to pull in film info - title, runtime, etc)
- **sched_date** (uses datetime to set a specific showtime on a specific date)

I guess I might have to abandon using datetime if there's any way to do this?

Any help would be hot! Much thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: I updated the post with the basic showtimes table I have now. 

My desired output, from a user perspective would look something like this: http://codysilfies.com/p9test/display.php (but without the 'All Showtimes for Submitted Films' section)

Ideally, if say, I was adding showtimes for 'John Carter', I'd just have to put in the coming week's showtimes (for example 2:00  4:00  6:00 8:00) and be able to submit them for all days starting 5/15 thru 5/20.  On the user end they pick a date and it'll display the showtimes for all films on that day (I've got this bit mostly figured out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 date fields with names `from_date` and `end_date` in your PHP form. In your PHP form submit code you then need to use the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and start from `from_date` and use the [DateTime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method to loop till `end_date` is reached. Please note you need to first convert the 2 dates i.e. `from_date` and `end_date` to datetime using either  new DateTime('YYYY-MM-DD') or using [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

In the loop simply send insert commands to MySQL to insert the rows to your DB.

Comment: Awesome - I don't know why I never thought of using a loop (really...what other way is there? Haha).  As I'm very unfamilliar with loops and the DateTime::add method...I might need a bit more assistance in figuring out the syntax. So I've got start_date and end_date, but from there I'm a bit lost.  Am I correct in understanding that DateTime will essentially count the days between the start/end and loop that many times? So..

`for(start_date =! end_date) {
 ...Add Row to table
 date_add(start_date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));}`

...am I at all close?

Comment: You are perfectly sound! That is the way to address the issue! Cheers!